# How to magnify touch point of bitmap in android?

Tags: java, android, zooming, magnify

I'm trying to implement magnifier in my android application. On touching a bitmap it should be zoomed to some ratio and showed aside.I'm not getting the exact bitmap region where i touched on bitmap.Can anyone give me a solution.This is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = new BitmapShader(modelBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint();
matrix1.postScale(2f, 2f, mouseDownX, mouseDownY);
bitmap.setLocalMatrix(matrix1);
paint.setShader(bitmap);
canvas.drawCircle(60,230, (int) (width * 0.10), paint);
```

Here mouseDownX and mouseDownY are touch co-ordinates. I'm not getting the exact area of bitmap where i touched.

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried and explain what's not working. If you want developers to just write this code for you, it'll probably cost you money and this probably isn't the right place for it.

Comment: Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Class which will extend `ImageView` class and Override the `onTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` methods. Get the tapped location and draw the touched section on canvas in any shape you want.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class CodesforMagnifierImageView extends AppCompatImageView
{

    private PointF zoomPosition;
    private boolean zooming = false;
    private Matrix matrix;
    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private int sizeOfMagnifier = 200;

    public CodesforMagnifierImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CodesforMagnifierImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public CodesforMagnifierImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        zoomPosition = new PointF(0, 0);
        matrix = new Matrix();
        paint = new Paint();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();

        zoomPosition.x = event.getX();
        zoomPosition.y = event.getY();

        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                zooming = true;
                this.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                zooming = false;
                this.invalidate();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (!zooming)
        {
            buildDrawingCache();
        }
        else
        {

            bitmap = getDrawingCache();
            shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(shader);
            matrix.reset();
            matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPosition.x, zoomPosition.y);
            paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);
            canvas.drawCircle(zoomPosition.x, zoomPosition.y, sizeOfMagnifier, paint);
        }
    }


}
```

Use it in following way:

```
<com.utilities.CodesforMagnifierImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapShader bitmap = new BitmapShader(modelBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, 
TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint();
matrix1.postScale(2f, 2f, mouseDownX, mouseDownY);
bitmap.setLocalMatrix(matrix1);
paint.setShader(bitmap);
canvas.drawCircle(mouseDownX, mouseDownY, (int) (width * 0.10), paint);
```

please see [How to magnify/zoom part of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055525/how-to-magnify-zoom-part-of-image)